# excel vba opening various excel file types

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a macro that will open excel files.  They could be xls or xlsm or xlsx depending on who submits them I have a number of macros that open a specific file type but am stuck on the code to use that will open an xls or xlsx or xlsm file.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Sub FileOpener()

Dim userFileName As Variant

userFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks, *.xl*", _
                                           Title:="Choose a Workbook to Open", _
                                           MultiSelect:="False")
If userFileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=userFileName
End If

End Sub
```